# Traversing through table rows and disabling input in second column

Tags: javascript, html-select

please have a look at the below code.

```
<table>
 <tr>
     <td>
          <select name='td1'>
               <option value=1>One</option>
               <option value=2>Two</option>
               <option value=3>Three</option>
          </select>
     </td>
     <td>
          <select name='td2'>
               <option value=1>One</option>
               <option value=2>Two</option>
               <option value=3>Three</option>
          </select>
     </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName("tr").each(function(){
   $(this).getElementsByTagName("td")[1].getElementsByTagName("select").disabled=true;
})
</script>
```

Requirement is
1. By default, the select field in the second column(i.e, second td's select) must be disabled.
2. the second select field can only be enabled only when the user selects third option in the first select field.
3. the solution must be in pure javascript( not using jquery)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I cannot see any code here, if you want some JavaScript solution.

Comment: @vahdet html code

Comment: I mean, it'd be better if you have shared what you have tried: Where is the JS code you have tried?

Comment: in one table row there are two td's and each td contains a select tag. now when page loads the page,  second td's select must be disabled and only when the user selects the thrid option from select dropdown of first td then automatically enable the second td's select

Comment: here i just tried to disable the second  td's select

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("tr").each(function(){
$(this).getElementsByTagName("td")[1].getElementsByTagName("select").disabled=true;
})

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr')).forEach(tr => {
    const secondSelect = tr.children[1].querySelector('select');
    secondSelect.disabled = true;
    tr.querySelector('td select').addEventListener('change', function() {
        secondSelect.disabled = (this.value != 3);
    });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, when page loads the second select must be disabled. it can enable only when user selects the third option in first select.

Comment: You can use the `disabled` attribute in your HTML code then to start with the disabled state.

Comment: okay code is working, but how to add disable attribute to only second td's select using javascript. i dont have access to html code, since it is generating from the confirmit tool

Answer (score 1):

This code will work only for one row having two select option,which is perfectly suitable for your example.

```
var selectTag = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('select')
    selectTag[1].disabled = true;  
    selectTag[0].addEventListener("change", function(){
      if(selectTag[0].value == 3){
        selectTag[1].disabled = false;
      }
      else{
        selectTag[1].disabled = true;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

for disabeling the `select` you just need to add the `disabled` attribute using [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) , or `element.disabled = true` , then [listen for the change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) of the other select and check its value, if it's equal to `3` remove the `disabled`,

```js
let td2 = document.querySelector('[name=td2]');
td2.disabled = true ;

let td1 = document.querySelector('[name=td1]');
td1.addEventListener('change', function() {

  if (+this.value === 3) // the + sign is a shorthand for parseInt
    td2.disabled = false ;
  else
    td2.disabled = true ;
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name='td1'>
        <option value='1'>One</option>
        <option value='2'>Two</option>
        <option value='3'>Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name='td2'>
        <option value='1'>One</option>
        <option value='2'>Two</option>
        <option value='3'>Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your code worked, but what if there are multiple rows?

Comment: i mean, multiple <tr> with same setup